# What is the process for detecting a 0.2 gallon/hour leak in an underground petrol tank with an accuracy of 95% or more?

Tags: modeling, computational-statistics

Current EPA regulation stipulates that SIR (Statistical Inventory Reconciliation) vendors must be able to detect a leak of 0.2 gallons/hour with a probability of 0.95 or higher, and a false alarm rate of no more than 0.05.

This method is used because most gas stations manually dip their tank with a long stick and compare the difference from the previous day with the total amount that was dispensed. If the manual dip differs 450 gallons since yesterday, but the pumps dispensed 430 gallons, that would imply a leak of 30 gallons. However due to the manual nature of dipping and huge variations that may occur, Statistical Reconciliation Analysis methods are adopted that compute a leak rate using nothing more than:
1) Daily Stick Reading
2) Deliveries of fuel
3) daily dispensed reading

How would one go about determining this? I am guessing it's not a simply formula, but what steps or analytical methods are best to use or what steps would you take to determine this?